# Convert Highchart to multiple y axis

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a working graph using Highcharts with data from a mySQL database. I need it now to view the lines on different axis so that the chart is better laid out.

Here's my code and JSFiddle for the graph with my data:

http://jsfiddle.net/petenaylor/tGfau/3/

```
(function($){ // encapsulate jQuery

$(function() {
var seriesOptions = [],
    yAxisOptions = [],
    seriesCounter = 0,
    names = ['Electric', 'Oil', 'Gas'],
    colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;

$.each(names, function(i, name) {

    $(function() {

$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container',
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 12
        },

        title : {
            text : 'Energy Prices'
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'Electric',

            <?php 
            $result = mysql_query (" SELECT * FROM energyprices ORDER BY id ASC") or die (mysql_error());
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            extract($row);
            $date = strtotime($row['pDate']);
            $date = $date."000"; // convert from Unix timestamp to JavaScript time
            $data1[] = "[$date, $electric]";
            }
            ?>


            data: [<?php echo join($data1, ',') ?>],
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        },{
            name : 'Oil',


            <?php 
            $result = mysql_query (" SELECT * FROM energyprices ORDER BY id ASC") or die (mysql_error());
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            extract($row);
            $date = strtotime($row['pDate']);
            $date = $date."000"; // convert from Unix timestamp to JavaScript time
            $data2[] = "[$date, $oil]";
            }
            ?>


            data: [<?php echo join($data2, ',') ?>],
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        },{
            name : 'Gas',


            <?php 
            $result = mysql_query (" SELECT * FROM energyprices ORDER BY id ASC") or die (mysql_error());
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            extract($row);
            $date = strtotime($row['pDate']);
            $date = $date."000"; // convert from Unix timestamp to JavaScript time
            $data3[] = "[$date, $gas]";
            }
            ?>


            data: [<?php echo join($data3, ',') ?>],
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});

});

});



// create the chart when all data is loaded
function createChart() {

    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },









        /*yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return (this.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + this.value + '%';
                }
            },

            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 2,
                color: 'silver'
            }]
        },*/



        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return (this.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + this.value + '%';
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Electric',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            },
            opposite: true

        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Oil',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value;
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            }

        }, { // Tertiary yAxis
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Gas',
                style: {
                    color: '#AA4643'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value;
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#AA4643'
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],









        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                compare: 'percent'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2
        },

        series: seriesOptions
    });
}

});
})(jQuery);
```

As you can see this works as it should, however, I need this to function like the below example. It's important that I have the y axis showing the values and the zoom must work. I have tried to adapt the below code with my own data but I get the issue unresponsive script. I think my data could be too much for the chart to handle.

http://jsfiddle.net/petenaylor/c73u5/5/

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Average Monthly Weather Data for Tokyo'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        }],
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value +'°C';
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            },
            opposite: true

        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value +' mm';
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            }

        }, { // Tertiary yAxis
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
                style: {
                    color: '#AA4643'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value +' mb';
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#AA4643'
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var unit = {
                    'Rainfall': 'mm',
                    'Temperature': '°C',
                    'Sea-Level Pressure': 'mb'
                }[this.series.name];

                return ''+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y +' '+ unit;
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 120,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 80,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Rainfall',
            color: '#4572A7',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

        }, {
            name: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
            type: 'spline',
            color: '#AA4643',
            yAxis: 2,
            data: [1016, 1016, 1015.9, 1015.5, 1012.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 1013.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7],
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            dashStyle: 'shortdot'

        }, {
            name: 'Temperature',
            color: '#89A54E',
            type: 'spline',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }]
    });
});

});
```

Can anyone help?

Many thanks

Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/mxrhS/

I did it by defining 3 yaxis, and then setting each series to use a different yaxis:

```
yAxis:[{opposite:false},{opposite:true},{opposite:true,offset:50}],
```

and

```
series: [{
                        name: 'Electric',
                        yAxis:0,
```